# Open File Instead of Save File in Silverlight SaveFileDialog

Tags: file, silverlight, savefiledialog

In Silverlight, there is the SaveFileDialog which allows you to save a file to the user's local machine.  The dialog opens only allowing you to save the file.  What I'm looking for is a way to open the file similar to the dialog you get when downloading a file through the browser.

Aside from round-tripping the file to a server, or having the server generate the file (neither of which I can do), are there any options to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is: No silverlight doesn't allow that.

If somehow you know that full file path of the file you want to open you might be able to get the hosting browser to navigate to that file but you may hit other browser based road blocks.  Of course, discovering the full file path of a file is pratically impossible to do in this scenario.  You'd have to get the user to paste the full path into some text box then try to convince the browser to navigate to it.